# What is equivalent of linq IndexOf(p) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying convert my Linq code to SQL query. I dont know what is the equivalent of `IndexOf(p)` in SQL.

Please help me to convert my below Linq code to SQL query

```
var listOfSearchValue = searchValue.ToUpper().Split(null);
var sqlQuery =
            _dataContext.table1.GetQuery()
                .Where(
                    d =>
                        (listOfSearchValue.Any(p => d.doctorsname.ToUpper().IndexOf(p) > -1)
```

Comment: Which SQL server are you using? Did you search its documentation?

Comment: Are you looking for [CHARINDEX()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) string function?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for [`CHARINDEX()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) string function.

Syntax:

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

Sample query:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX( 'R', 'SQL SERVER')
```

will return output as `7`

and if the searching text/character is not exists in the given string, it will return the output as `0`.

Example:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX( 'X', 'SQL SERVER')
```